# Get query string of parent page from child page

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I need to know whether is it possible to get the query string of parent page? I have something like this:

I have one page say client.aspx, now i have opened this page with query string and this page has one window and when i click on particular button window get pop's up and in that i am loading another page say clientcontacts.aspx, i want query string of client.aspx on clientcontatcts.aspx.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Has the child been opened as a popup window with window.open?  If so, you can use:

```
window.opener
```

to get the parent page (see http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_opener.asp).  Then you can use:

```
window.opener.location.search
```

to get the query portion of the url (see http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_search.asp)

Answer (score 1):

You can also pass this QueryString value to pop up page and fetch the value in the child page.

Comment: i am not supposed to do in that way.. i have been told to access that query string, i cannot even use hidden control..

Answer (score 1):

Can you use `Request.UrlReferrer` in this context? or as Saurabh says, just pass the querystring from the parent to the child page?

Comment: I have found problems with doing things with the referrer is that some internet security software in the past has stripped all referrers from HTTP requests, even ones to the same domain. This isn't common but it can happen and will be very hard to debug (from experience). Just a word of caution. ;-)

Comment: Worth bearing in mind as you say, it's a bit of environmental oddity though. I suppose if you're routing your web traffic through anything, the contents of the response could always be malformed, our proxies at work strip all kind of content from pages, I'm not sure whether you'd want to pander to this and code around it, or put it down as the clients issue and point them toward less draconian security software!

Comment: The latter is certainly preferable since as you say really the problem is their end and in my experience no matter where the problem is clients expect *you* to fix things. But yeah, more something to be aware of in case you ever do get complaints if you go down this line. :)